# how to run (or not) a cron job based on the results of another cron job

Tags: apache, cron, cpanel, job-scheduling

I need to execute a cron job based on whether or not the cron job that ran before it was at least partially successful, I am trying to set up conditions for the run... sometimes these condition would be on the local or remote machine...

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can share a common-file in which the first job will write its status and second cron job will read it an decide on that basis weather it should proceed or not.

In case of remote machine you may share that file on network.

Comment: AH thanks! that sounds logical, do you know where I could get more details on how to do that?

Comment: @user3280972 I think you will have to write it yourself. There is one more logical solution to your problem that, since both of the cron job are dependent on each other you may club them, otherwise if you share the resource such as file between them you also need to take care of synchronization and concurrency.